# "Double gradient" design for ecotoxicology of particulate substances

Tags: multiple-regression, predictor, gradient

We are designing an investigation on effects of microplastic particles (MP) on experimental soil in growth chambers. Question: Is there a significant effect? And if so, what is the form of the relationship (linear, dose-response, threshold, ...?). We have cooked up an experimental design that, to our knowledge, has never been used before in experimental toxicology, and would be very grateful to get feedback.

We have the capacity to run 50 pots, each of two liters volume. To each pot, an increasing amount of MPs will be added to form a concentration gradient (0, 2, 4, ... 98 units of MP; no replication of the "levels" of the gradient). For analysis, we will use some sort of regression analysis, the specifics depending on the dependent variables (we have a long list of measured parameters).

But there is a problem: MPs are particles, not a liquid. If you add particles to soil, you modify many physical and, in consequence, chemical and biological characteristics. Especially when adding larger amounts of MPs (as on the right side of the gradient), there is the danger to experimentally confuse toxic and "pure particle" effects.

Solution: We also add quartz particles to the experimental pots (quartz of the same particle size as the MP). Quartz is chemically and biologically inert, thus, all effects surpassing quartz effects can be attributed to MP toxicity. For this approach, a logical design would be to run two experiments in parallel: a MP and a quartz experiment, and compare results.

But this is a pain, as it would halve the sample size (n = 50) and lower test power. Everything we invest on the quartz side, we lose on the MP side of the experiment. Not good.

Our next idea is to set up the MP gradient as described above, using all 50 pots. In addition, we randomly (!) add a varying amount of quartz to each pot, the amounts again forming a gradient with no replication of concentration "levels". In other words: the MP and the quartz concentration both follow a gradient, and the "levels" of the two gradients are randomly assigned to each other. Thus, we finally have 47 "gradient pots", and additionally a zero-MP/zero-quartz, a zero-MP, and a zero-quartz pot to get baseline values for the two parameters.

We then analyze the data with a multiple regression model, using (1) MP concentration as explanatory variable;(2) the total concentration of added particles (MP + quartz) as (metric) covariate. This model may be improved by including various forms of the relationship between MP and total mass, and by maybe including quartz mass, etc. - but you get the general approach.

I never have come across a setup like this in the literature, although it seems like a natural and simple idea for the experimental ecotoxicology of particles. Does this make sense at all? Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: Why can't you simply have a constant amount of "additive", where the additive is a mixture of MP and quartz, in varying ratios? E.g. you'd start with 0 units of MP and 98 units of quartz for the first pot, 2 MP and 96 quartz for the second one, etc. until the 50th pot gets 98 units of MP and 0 of quartz.

Comment: @Igor F. - Thank you for your super quick reply. Your idea would establish a relationship between the (potential) toxicity of MP and quartz concentration - this is exactly what we need to avoid. Randomly assigning quartz concentration "levels" to MP "levels" decouples particle effects from toxic effects.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought there are potentially two effects: "pure particle" ( both MP and quartz) and potential toxicity (only for MP). My proposed setup would keep the "pure particle" effect constant and any difference in whatever outcome you measure could be assigned to MP toxicity.

Comment: @Igor F. - It took me a while to see where the misunderstanding is, because your idea is perfectly logical. It's this: not only do we want to test  for significant effects of MP on soil parameters, but also understand the form of the relationship. For this, toxicologists always start at level of zero contamination ("control") where nothing happens, not treatment is applied, etc. Your suggestion indeed differentiates toxic and "pure particle" effects, but modifies the soils of all experimental units.